# $G$ abelian $\{ a^ib^j : a^m = b^n = 1, a^2=b^3 \}$, prove that $G=\langle c:c^k=1 \rangle$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

> Let G be an abelian group $\{ a^i b^j : a^m = b^n = 1, a^2=b^3 \}$. Prove that $G=\langle c:c^k=1 \rangle$ with $k=\gcd(3m,2n)$. Hint: consider the element $ab^{-1}$.

This should be easy but I'm having a hard time with it. I think even with the hint that $ab^{-1}$ is supposed to be the generator $c$.

So that point it to prove that all the powers of $c$ represent every element in the group. My first idea was to notice that $a^{2m}b^{3n}=(ab)^h=1$ where $h=lcm(2m,3n)$. So $(ab)^h$ could be a generator, but I am not sure if all the elements of $G$ are represented, and it seems it does not use the hint.

I could use some help on this. Thanks.

OK so with the (other) hint, $(ab^{-1})^2=b$ and $(ab^{-1})^3=a$, so $(ab^{-1})^{2n}=b^n=1$ and $(ab^{-1})^{3m}=a^m=1$, that is how we get the $3m$ and $2n$. $k=\gcd(3m, 2n)$, and I find then there exists 2 integers, $h$ and $g$ such that $kh=3m \implies k=\frac{3m}{h}$ and $kg=2n \implies k=\frac{2n}{g}$. However still stuck here.

Comment: Hint: Simplify $(ab^{-1})^2$ and $(ab^{-1})^3$.

Comment: Ah yes, $(ab^{-1})^2=b$, and $(ab^{-1})^3=a$.

Comment: Your last paragraph doesn't make much sense.  What is $\gcd(3m,2n)$ when $m=2$ and $n=3$ for instance?

Comment: @BrianMoehring yes i see your point i guess it doesn't make much sense. I am hung up on the cases where the numbers don't come out nice. Not sure if its even possible but what if $m=5$ and $n=7$, for instance? Then $k$ is 1, but even in any case where k is smaller than either $m$ or $n$? Since $m$ and $n$ are the orders $a$ and $b$ it doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: Let's let $k$ be the order of $c=ab^{-1}$. Since you showed that $c^{2n}=1$, you know $k$ divides $2n$. Since you showed that $c^{3m}=1$, you know $k$ divides $3m$. Since $k$ divides $2n$ and $3m$, you know $k$ divides $\text{GCD}(2n,3m)$.

Comment: @AndrewOstergaard thank you, I always miss this point, but since you've stated it I obviously see it. So, i guess the last point is: is this enough to show that every element of $G$ is generated by $c=ab^{-1}$?

Comment: Since $G$ is generated by $a$ and $b$, and $c^2=b$ and $c^3=a$, it follows that $G$ is generated by $c$. You've also shown that if $k$ is the order of $c$, then $k$ divides $\text{GCD}(2n,3m)$, so $k\le\text{GCD}(2n,3m)$. You need to show $\text{GCD}(2n,3m)\le k$.

Comment: I'm also not sure how to do that part of the proof, so perhaps some other helpful person will help us out. Below, I've posted a completely different proof that (1) $G$ is cyclic, and (2) the order of $G$ is $\text{GCD}(2n,3m)$.

Answer (score 4):

We can find out how to express our finitely generated group $G$ as a direct product of cyclic groups by finding the Smith normal form of

$$\begin{bmatrix} m & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & n & -3 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Let's perform the following row and column operations: first adding $2\cdot\text{Row }1$ to $\text{Row }2$, we have

$$\begin{bmatrix} m & 0 & 2 \\ 2m & n & 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Switching the rows, we have

$$\begin{bmatrix} 2m & n & 1 \\ m & 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Switching the first and last columns, we have

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & n & 2m \\ 2 & 0 & m \end{bmatrix}.$$

Adding $-2\cdot\text{Row }1$ to $\text{Row }2$, we have

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & n & 2m \\ 0 & -2n & -3m \end{bmatrix}.$$

Adding $-n\cdot\text{Column }1$ to $\text{Column }2$, we have

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 2m \\ 0 & -2n & -3m \end{bmatrix}.$$

Adding $-2m\cdot\text{Column }1$ to $\text{Column }3$, we have

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -2n & -3m \end{bmatrix}.$$

Finally, multiplying $\text{Row }2$ by $-1$, we have

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2n & 3m \end{bmatrix}.$$

This last matrix will have the same Smith normal form as our original matrix. Let $k=\text{GCD}(2n,3m)$. Then the Smith normal form will be

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & k & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$

It follows that $G$ is a cyclic group of order $k$.

Comment: I have voted this up, this is very interesting, although just beyond what I have studied so far. Just googling about the Smith normal form right now, looks very powerful.

Comment: I appreciate the up-vote. I'm not sure what the best reference is for Smith normal form, but I learned it from the book by Dummit and Foote. That book discusses how you can use the relations of finitely generated abelian group to get a matrix whose Smith normal form will tell you how to express the group as a direct product of cyclic groups.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind I understand why this isn't the solution that you would have hoped for. If you want I'll delete it, and then perhaps more people will have a look at your problem, since it would then be an unanswered problem. Let me know.

Comment: No please leave it here, I just haven't accepted it yet hoping for an alternative, more group-theory-based approach, but this may be the best way. For my algebra 1 course, which I just finished, also used Dummit and Foote, but we only got through chapter 4. The assistant for this course also hasn't been able to prove this last part either.

Comment: To add to this solution: If we follow the generators as well as the relations, this method shows $a^{-1}b^2\, ({}=ab^{-1})$ generates $G$, so done this way, we would be able to do the problem even without the initial hint to consider $ab^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

Set $c = ab^{-1}.$  Then obviously $c \in G,$ so $\langle c\rangle \subseteq G$ but also since $c^2 = b$ and $c^3 = a,$ we have $G = \langle a,b\rangle \subseteq \langle c \rangle$ so $\langle c\rangle = G.$

The group presentation is then
$$\begin{align*}G &= \langle a, b  \mid a^m = b^n = 1, a^2 = b^3\rangle \\ &= \langle c \mid c^{3m} = c^{2n} = 1, c^6=c^6\rangle \\ &= \langle c \mid c^{3m}=c^{2n}=1\rangle \\ &= \langle c \mid c^{\gcd(3m,2n)} = 1\rangle\end{align*}$$

Comment: I upvoted your elegant solution. Very nicely done!

Comment: @AndrewOstergaard Thanks.  Your solution showcases the more general tool.  All I did was use the fact $ab^{-1}$ generates $G$ to skip to the last step of your proof.  If anything, all this does is shows how the fore-knowledge/intuition of generators can simplify things.

Comment: I think your solution is shorter and more elegant. Your solution is also more elementary, so it will be accessible to people who haven't learned Smith normal form yet. You noted that my solution can be used to show that $ab^{-1}$ is a generator, but it takes some work to show that, whereas your solution makes it obvious. All in all, I like your solution the best! I hope it gets picked as the top solution!